# python black scholes error

Tags: python, finance

I am running python via spyder in anaconda. I am a new python user. I am trying to run a black-scholes option pricer by finding code on the internet. I found this site:

https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783284375/4

and start to copy the code but get a lot of errors and I'm not sure why.

All I did was copy the initial bit of code:

```
from math import *
def bs_call(S,X,T,r,sigma):
    d1 = (log(S/X)+(r+sigma*sigma/2.)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1-sigma*sqrt(T)
    return S*CND(d1)-X*exp(-r*T)*CND(d2)
```

The errors I get are the following:

```
'from math import *' use; unable to detect undefined names
log may be undefined
sqrt may be undefined
CND may be undefined
```

I thought by importing math via: `from math import *` it would define all these variables for me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you attached, `CND` is a function that is defined later in the article. You had to copy and run the whole code!

The other functions (log and sqrt) are imported well, but your IDE seems to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, why would my IDE ignore this and how could I fix that? Thank you

Comment: You can in turn ignore the IDE =)

Comment: I don't understand, sorry I am a python novice! I have explicitly defined the 4 variables from math that I need to import by doing this:from math import log
from math import exp
from math import sqrt
from math import pi, however, I now get the error when running: runfile('L:/Gordon/Python Training/untitled1.py', wdir='L:/Gordon/Python Training')

Answer (score 0):

NumPy and SciPy provide everything needed. I suggest the following code to eschew dependencies.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def bs_call(S, X, t, r, sigma):
    assert S>=0 and X>=0 and sigma>=0 and t>=0 and r >=0, "All inputs should be non-negative"
    assert S > 0 and X > 0, "Inputs \'S\' (stock price) and \'X\' (strike) should be positive."

    d_1 = (np.log(S/X) + (r + 0.5*sigma**2)*t) / (sigma * np.sqrt(t))
    d_2 = d_1 - sigma * np.sqrt(t)
    
    return stats.norm.cdf(d_1, 0, 1)*S - stats.norm.cdf(d_2, 0, 1)*X*np.exp(-r*t)
```

Naturally, `log()` and `exp()` can be used from `math` package rather than `numpy` as well.